# Как используя mysql получить все дубликаты в строках таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `people`. У неё 2 столбца `id` и `fio`

> **fio** - Фамилия Имя Отчество

Мне нужно найти не по конкретному запросу, а получить все имеющиеся дубликаты

Например (сокр.):

1 И А И
2. А И Б
3. И А В
4. И А И
5. А И Г
6. А И А
7. А И Б

Я из этого должен найти и получить следующие идентификаторы: `1,4; 2,7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно получить идентификаторы дублей в виде строк через запятую, то как-то так

```
 SELECT fio, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY  id SEPARATOR ',')
 FROM people
 GROUP BY fio
 HAVING count(id) > 1
```